# get list response from ajax call c#

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax

I need to use the info from the list returned in a method that calls my ajax to c#.

This is the method, seems working fine:

```
 public JsonResult getComandes(int id)
        {
            using (var db = new daw_tenda()) //estat 1 = acabat, estat 2 = en curs.
            {

               var llistacomandes = db.Comandes.Where(x => x.usuaris_id == id).ToList();

                return Json(llistacomandes.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
```

This is my ajax:

```
$.ajax({
            url: "/Perfil/getComandes",
            type: 'get',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                id: $("#idsesion").val()
            },
            success: function (response) {
                $("#contingutcomandes").show();
                $("#contingutperfil").hide();
                if (response)
                {
                    console.log(response);
                }

            }
        });
```

I'm not getting any response, neither it's working first two jquery show and hide and i don't know what am i doing wrong, my method is working fine and is returning the list but i can't get it from the ajax call, what i have to fix?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm -- since the method is correctly returning the list, the symptoms suggest the `success` function isn't being called. Have you tried changing `success` to `complete`? This'll execute even if the request is failing, which may shed some light.

Maybe something like:

```
complete: function(resp){
    console.log("Ding!");
    console.log(resp);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that is working for this case! I don't know how to get the list of objects in the response now, would you answer me that please?

Comment: Hmm. Well, if `complete` is firing, and `success` isn't, chances are the request is failing. Instead of `console.log(resp)`, try `console.log(resp.statusCode())`. The status code will help focus your investigation.

Comment: Gotcha. I'm not _too_ familiar with C# APIs, but should the `id` value be part of `data`, or appended to your `url`?

Comment: There is different ways but that one is working because if not linq query will not work. All c# is working the problem is at the step to return to ajax.

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the method in Visual Studio and step through it line-by-line to see where the exception happens. There's clearly something it doesn't like.

Comment: That can't be right -- you're getting an Internal Server Error, suggesting an error on the server.

Comment: I'm debugging every single step and it's all fine, no exception, only getting that error from console

Comment: I'm not sure what to tell you then. It's odd that you'd watch your server send back a successful response, only to have jQuery display a Server Error.